# Как на уровне железа конкурируют 2 процесса?

Tags: многопоточность, железо

Как на уровне железа реализуется взаимодействие многопоточных\многопроцессорных программ, т.е. хочу представить как это реально происходит, "бегут" 2+ электрических заряда по цепи от 2+ ядерного процессора и все они хотят обратиться к диску, в каком месте они встречаются и как достигается понимания того что кто-то первый, а кто-то второй, третий и т.п. ? и что будет если они будут абсолютно одновременны? Или например тоже самое но с записью в RAM, как каждый процесс успевает занять себе место но которое гарантированно не занял кто-то другой в эту же миллисекунду.

Comment: Одновременного доступа к RAM быть не может. Только один ЦП может одновременно читать RAM (в обычных ПК). Другой ЦП будет ожидать пока RAM освободится. Для того что бы все друг друга не ждали - используется кеш.

Comment: Одновременного доступа к диску быть не может, "дисковый цикл" длится дольше чем цикл обращения в ram. Пока с диска не будет вычитан весь запрошеный обьём (условный кластер данных, от 512 байт) - диск занят и не может отдать информацию паралельному запросу. В многопоточных системах желательно делать "очереди" обращения к диску и возможно какие-то другие приёмы, позволяющие избегать взаимного ожидания, иначе скорость работы программы может значительно падать.

Comment: @nick_n_a - оба утверждения верны для какой-то 386 машины, которая едва хромает. В современных системах и память работает в несколько каналов, и SSD диск может обслуживать за раз целую пачку IOPS.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, но вопрос как раз в том как эти очереди образуются, когда 2 потока одновременно захотят обратится к диску, как определяется "победитель" и как это устроено на физическом уровне.

Comment: @gbd У памяти остался ras и cas, Не слышал что бы для памяти был какой-то многопоточный протокол. Для кеш-памяти - может быть всё что производитель пожелает. Для диска возможно такое есть, т.к. диск имеет интерфейс и по сути это "компьютер в компьютере" ))  IOPS не слышал - почитаю.

Comment: Я думаю что "победитель" может вычисляться случайным образом, но так же вероятнее всего собирается статистика, и предпочтение отдаётся более обделённому процессу что бы выравнять статистику.

Comment: @gbg, в любом случае проблема диспетчеризации одновремнных транзакций от CPU к внешнему ресурсу никуда не исчезла. Как именно работает этот аппаратный распределенный диспетчер  это know how создателей каждого чипа

Comment: @nick_n_a начните узнавать о современной архитектуре прямо сейчас - с Википедии хотя бы https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @avp конфликты синхронизации исключаются на уровне алгоритмов, а железо предоставляет средства для реализации примитивов синхронизации

Comment: Межпроцессным взаимодействием знанимется ОС. Межпоточным - программист. Как там на уровне железа, не принципиально для программиста, этим занимаются железячники. Если реально интересует эта тема и есть свободное время, то я бы начал гуглить соответствующие книги. Я натыкался на Таненбаума - "Архитектура компьютера".

Comment: @gbg многоканальный режим не означает многопоточный. По двум каналам можно записать больше информации в еденицу времени, но физически - шина адреса - общая, шина данных - раздельная - это означает просто что мы можем быстрее писать/читать, а не то что два thread могут иметь произвольный доступ к памяти.

Comment: @gbg, насколько я понял вопрос, его автора интересует, как например, разруливается ситуация одновременной выдачи транзакций на чтение от 2-х L1 к общему L2 ( т.е. как именно вход L2 выбирает запросы из подсоединенных к нему очередей каждого L1)

Comment: @nick_n_a http://163.239.27.184/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Adaptive-Memory-Controller-for-High-Performance-Multi-channel-Memory.pdf

Разные треды цепляются к разным каналам.

Comment: @nick_n_a - про NUMA еще почитайте, узнаете много нового и полезного, чтобы отвечать точно, а не домыслами.

Comment: @dbg Хорошо, допустим можно, но если два процесса обращаются к RAM, то нет гарантии что это обращение  можно распаралелить. Обращение в память можно распаралелить с некоторой верятностью. А если на плате два процессора то как? То всё усложняется. Распаралеливание допустим возможно, но что бы оно дало большой процент прироста производительности - надо знать на что обратить внимание.

Comment: Если на плате два CPU - мы попадаем в веселый мир NUMA, когда обращение в память соседнего CPU идет через высокоскоростную шину, например, через QPI https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickPath_Interconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диск и память сильно отличаются. Единственное что справедливо будет и для диска и для памяти - кто последний сделал запись - того и тапки. Т.е. если вы не используете принудительные блокировки - может оказаться что по адресу, куда вы записали информацию - она уже стёрта потоком, который работает паралельно.

Касательно RAM. Тут есть три фактора - ЦП, КЕШ, ОС, многоканальность. С RAM всё проще, пока один ЦП делает обращение в физическую память - остальные ЦП - ждут. Каким именно образом организован приоритет ожидания - затрудняюсь сказать. Скорее всего по номеру процессора, и может отличаться от версии ЦП. Так как программа чаще всего не работает исключительно с памятью - то после ожидания другой ЦП получит доступ к RAM. Надо не забывать, что **ОС** может ограничивать/подавлять излишнюю активность потока, если ей нужно паралельно ещё делать какие-то задачи, в т ч обслуживание ОС. Поэтому приоритет будет зависеть ещё и от версии ОС, её загруженности и колличества одновременно запущенных программ и каких именно программ тоже (т.к. одна программа может грузить ЦП на полную, а другая спать). Так же **кеш** памяти встроеный в ЦП - очень облегчает операции с памятью. В современных ПК уже нету внешнего кеш. При выключеном кеш ЦП работает в разы медленнее. Обращение в RAM при включеном кеш - могут не происходить, если в КЕШ всё поместилось. При использовании **двухканальной** памяти, или многоканальной - возможна упаковка обращения к RAM от двух потоков в одно обращение, что так же даст небольшой прирост производительности (т.к. вероятность такой возможноти имеет некоторый % вероятности).

C диском всё гораздо сложнее. Во первых работа с диском идет не напрямую, а через драйвер, поэтому приоритет или одновременность обращения - решает драйвер. Учитывая то что очень часто дисковые операции обьеденяются вместе и кешируется - то вполне возможно что потоки перейдут в ожидание в разнове время, но завершится ожидание дисковой операции примерно в одинаковое время. После физической операции ввода вывода - управление перейдёт драйверу ввода вывода, а уже драйвер ввода вывода передаст управление ОС. Вероятнее всего ОС отдаст предпочтение самому обделённому потоку, что бы выровнять перекос по быстродействию (если у потоков одинаковые приоритеты). Работа с диском напрямую в обход драйвера - задача очень сложная - практически не используется.

При работе в многопоточной среде - для разных случаев используют разные приёмы для ускорения работы. Думаю знание железа тут не сильно поможет. Лучше почитать статьи по мнопоточной сортировке например, так же есть описание других многопоточных процессов - и там почитать особенности. Часть таких особенностей обусловлены железом, а часть - получена экспериментальным путём.

Comment: Для NUMA (а это все современные многосокетные серверы) утверждение о том, что другие ЦП - ждут - ложное. Потому что в этих системах каждый процессор располагает собственным контроллером памяти, к которому подключены его "персональные" банки памяти.

Comment: @gbg странно что вы в своём ответе не написали что такое numa, и что такое многоканальность. По идее, надо просто понимать в каких случаях работает NUMA, в каких случаях срабатывает многоканальность, и возможно дать % улучшения при использовании той или иной технологии, он там есть. Пожалуй я дал общие представления как работает память. Возможно тут есть смысл настоять на том что бы автор уточнил что он хочет.

Comment: Прошу прощения - неверно прочел

Answer (score 2):

Взаимодействие многопоточных програм реализуется в первую очередь на базе логических примитивов синхронизации, которые в свою очередь реализуются за счет вполне понятных логических узлов. На уровень отдельных электронных компонентов тут уже спускаться не нужно.

Один маленький конкретный пример - логический примитив "атомарная переменная (std::atomic в C++)". Для реализации ее в примитивном процессоре, у которого нет кэша и конвейера инструкций, операции чтения и записи в эту переменную выполнялись за одну машинную инструкцию.

На базе атомарной переменной уже можно сконструировать более сложные примитивы синхронизации - мьютекс и семафор. А уж с таким арсеналом можно много чего натворить.

Для того, чтобы это хоть как-то систематизировать и стандартизировать, суровые языки программирования с многопоточностью (C, C++, и т. д) вводят формальную модель памяти и машины, и дают описание своей работы в стандарте в рамках этой модели. Реализация модели на конкретном железе ложится на разработчиков компиляторов, которые в свою очередь располагают частью спецификаций на машинный код процессора.

При этом, некоторая часть этой спецификации является очень дорогой интеллектуальной собственностью разработчиков железа и выдается под суровыми NDA.

Comment: Вообще-то это описание немного более высокого уровня, чем описание процессов,  происходящих в самом железе.

Comment: До уровня железа спускаться нет практического смысла - получится сплошное UB, на которое будет влиять, например, версия микрокода процессора.

Comment: Да, железо оно такое, 2 последовательные версии уже могут быть на нижнем уровне не совместимы... Впрочем, ТС спрашивал как раз о железе -- *`"Как на уровне железа реализуется взаимодействие..."`*

Comment: @avp тут начнется разговор на уровне сферических коней в вакууме, потому что придется для объяснения выдумать модельный компьютер, на примере которого  вести изложение. Потому что конкретный алгоритм работы того же контроллера памяти в Интеле - большой-большой секрет. Все что из него торчит наружу - ассемблерные инструкции (https://habr.com/ru/post/157163/), позволяющие построить примитивы синхронизации.

Comment: @gbg спасибо, но интересно именно представить как на уровне "отдельных электронных компонентов"

Comment: В самом деле, есть тут проблема. Например, я не уверен, что знаю, как и что делается в чужих чипах, и точно не имею права рассказывать, как это сделано в наших...

Comment: @gbg интересует пример именно в вакууме, как это примерно может быть сделано, не какой то конкретный пример. Вот идет с 2 процессоров абсолютно одновременная команда записать в ячейку с одинаковым адресом, на каком этапе эти запросы встретятся и конфликт как решится?

Comment: Эта ситуация исключается раньше, на уровне написания программ. Если такое происходит, программа является багнутой и будет работать как попало.

Comment: @gbg допустим не запись в одну ячейку, а просто 2 процесса для разных задач и разных целей хотят сделать запись в RAM

Comment: Ну, берут и делают запись в RAM. Это может призойти одновременно, если они попали в разные NUMA-регионы, или контроллеру памяти удалось закинуть их в разные каналы. Это может произойти в произвольном порядке. Как это конкретно сложится трудно сказать, потому что факторов, на это влияющих - слишком много, и среди них есть черный ящик - алгоритм работы кэша и контроллера памяти.

Comment: @gbg для этого им каждому нужно узнать адрес или зарезервировать адрес куда писать

Comment: Ну так  это извстно уже на уровне программиста, к железу тут лезть не требуется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123831/discussion-between---and-gbg).